# how to show different colors in gauge dashboard in sales force?

Tags: visualforce

My requirement is in that gauge chart we have to show different colors up to 5.
for that i have created custom vf page, but in that i have to show only 2 different colors.
Here i'm pasted my vf page and class..

vf page:

```
<apex:page controller="TestPageController">
  <html>

<apex:chart height="250" width="450" animate="true" legend="true" data="{!data}" >
    <apex:axis type="Gauge" position="left" margin="-10" 
       minimum="0" maximum="10000" steps="2000" />
    <apex:gaugeSeries dataField="score" highlight="true" tips="true" donut="60" 
        colorSet="#FF0000,#FACC2E,#31B404,#8A084B">

    </apex:gaugeSeries>    
</apex:chart>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Controller is:

```
public class TestPageController {   

    public TestPageController(){

    }

    public List<gaugeData> getData() {
        double NPS_score = 0;
        Account score = [Select Id, Name, Amount_1__c, Amount_2__c,AnnualRevenue  From Account Where id='001i000000cxxM4' LIMIT 1];
         Account score1 = [Select Id, Name,  Amount_1__c From Account LIMIT 1];
        List<gaugeData> data = new List<gaugeData>();
        data.add(new gaugeData('AMT1', score.Amount_1__c));
        data.add(new gaugeData('AMT1', score.Amount_2__c));
        data.add(new gaugeData('AMT1', score.AnnualRevenue));



        return data;
    }
    public class gaugeData {
        public String name { get; set; }

        public decimal score { get; set; }



        public gaugeData(String name, decimal npsScore) {
            this.name = name;


            this.score = npsScore;

        }
    }
}
```

i have attached the screenshot also..
[image]

Comment: can you ellaborate more here .Your query is confusing to me .Write what you have achieved so far and what is not happening as expected

Comment: Documentation such as [Gauge Charts](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_charting_appearance_gauge_charts.htm) suggest that only a single value is supported. I presume the thinking is that the gauge style of presentation corresponds to see the speedometer of a car where there is only a single value. You could use a separate gauge per value.

Comment: i want to show 4 colors like (red,green,yellow....)in gauge chart, but now it shows only 2 different colors..                                                                                          How to show different colors in gauge chart????

Comment: I value means only 2 colors: the color used to show the value and the color for the rest of the gauge.

Comment: is there any other way to get the different colors in gauge chart????

Comment: any one help me regarding this issue how to fix the problem....

Comment: Use a [pie chart](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_charting_overview_simple_example.htm) instead.

Comment: is there any possibility to do gauge series using scalable vector graphics (SVG)????                                                                                                                  To showing different colors in gauge..?????????