# How to build a gauge dashboard on visual force page?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

Hi to all,
                i have created custom vf page, but in that i have to show only 2 different colors. Here i'm pasted my vf page and class..

**vf page:**

```
<apex:page controller="TestPageController">
  <html>

<apex:chart height="250" width="450" animate="true" legend="true" data="{!data}" >
<apex:axis type="Gauge" position="left" margin="-10" 
   minimum="0" maximum="10000" steps="2000" />
<apex:gaugeSeries dataField="score" highlight="true" tips="true" donut="60" 
    colorSet="#FF0000,#FACC2E,#31B404,#8A084B">

</apex:gaugeSeries>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class TestPageController {   

public TestPageController(){

}

public List<gaugeData> getData() {
    double NPS_score = 0;
    Account score = [Select Id, Name, Amount_1__c, Amount_2__c,AnnualRevenue  From Account Where id='001i000000cxxM4' LIMIT 1];
     Account score1 = [Select Id, Name,  Amount_1__c From Account LIMIT 1];
    List<gaugeData> data = new List<gaugeData>();
    data.add(new gaugeData('AMT1', score.Amount_1__c));
    data.add(new gaugeData('AMT1', score.Amount_2__c));
    data.add(new gaugeData('AMT1', score.AnnualRevenue));

    return data;
}
public class gaugeData {
    public String name { get; set; }

    public decimal score { get; set; }

    public gaugeData(String name, decimal npsScore) {
        this.name = name;

        this.score = npsScore;

    }
} //comment to allow code to be formatted
}
```

o/p:
below screenshot
[image]

BUT MY REQUIREMNT IS WE HAVE TO SHOW DIFFERENT COLORS LIKE THIS IN THE BELOW SCREENSHOT TO SHOW IN VISUAL FORCE PAGE....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments on [how to show different colors in gauge dashboard in sales force?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49407/how-to-show-different-colors-in-gauge-dashboard-in-sales-force) the apex:chart gauge in Visualforce only supports two colors.

A third-party chart that looks like it may meet your needs is the [Google Charts Gauge](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/gauge). Though it may not support the semi-circular presentation. (Note I have not tried to use that particular chart, but have found other Google Charts to work well.) If this feature is really important, I suggest you experiment with that or Google for other third-party solutions. Quite a lot of JavaScript is involved so use your browser's "Developer Tools" to spot syntax and logical errors.